# how to identify moderator or high repo user?

Tags: discussion

If any user get any down voted then how he can identify that his post down voted by moderator or high repo user?

Is there any way to identify them?
thanks

Comment: In addition to Iain's answer, up and down votes are equal. An upvote from a high rep user or from someone who joined the site half an hour ago are both worth the same. All that high-rep users and moderators can do in addition to voting is vote to close questions, which isn't really the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the exception of a successful series of close votes (which says who voted to close but not how they voted), all voting is anonymous.

Comment: One other (minor) exception: Close votes that were cast through the review system can be viewed on a user's profile.

Comment: Delete votes are also not exactly anonymous... Though few can see who cast them.